# subscribe to azure service bus topics with queues

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

Azure ServiceBus provides both queues and topics for the messaging. I want to know if instead of an application subscribing to a topic, can I queue do that? can we receive the topic messages into queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Queues are for unicast operations, sending to a specific single destination.
Topics are for multicast operations, broadcasting.

You cannot subscribe to a queue, only listen to it. You can subscribe to a topic and then... listen to it. The difference is in *who else* can receive messages sent to a queue vs topic.

When a message is sent to a queue, it will be received by one listener only (assuming listener successfully processes and completes the message).

When a message is sent to a topic (also called "published"), every single subscriber will get a *copy* of that message.

> can we receive the topic messages into queue?

Yes you can. You can enable [Auto Forwarding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) on one of the subscriptions and point to the destination queue. It doesn't have to be a queue, could be another topic. Important thing to remember is that Azure Service Bus broker will protect from excessive auto-forwarding by limiting it to up to 3 hops at most.

Comment: I was told that topics do not guarantee delivery, but a co-worker disagrees because, according to the documentation, a subscription act like a "virtual queue" which a receiver can get messages from. But I'm observing that if the receiver goes down, messages sent to a topic subscription get dead-lettered. Am I right that delivery is not guaranteed for topics or is there a way to make messages in the subscription "queue" stay there like a Service Bus Queue? Or is forwarding it to an actual queue the only way to do that?

Comment: "Topics do not guarantee delivery" - nonsense. Ask them to elaborate why and show you documentation that states so. A subscription is a queue, correct. Your messages sent to a topic end up in a subscription DLQ for a reason, not because topic is unreliable or doesn't guarantee delivery. Raise a separate question with details.

Comment: I don't think they were saying that topics are unreliable, just that if a receiver goes offline, then a message is sent, then they go back online, the receiver would not receive that message because it went to a dead-letter queue. Conversely, if using a Service Bus Queue and a receiver goes down before a message is sent, the message will remain in the queue until the receiver comes back online and "completes" the message. I think the question is, can a topic exhibit the same behavior as a queue in that the message will remain in the subscription queue until completed?

Comment: Sorry, that's just nonsense. A topic is a way to route a message to multiple subscriptions. Once a message is in a subscription, it's not different than to be in a queue. The fact that consumers come and go doesn't matter at all. The whole point is to have decoupled producers and consumers. Queues or topics/subscriptions. I willing to bet money that the issue you've experienced was either a misconfiguration of the ASB client or a flaw in the consumer code. Raise a different question or reach ping me at feldman.sean on gmail.